# How to create bootable ISO from segmented Windows 7 image on El Capitan

Tags: mac, usb, iso

I have a canned Windows 7 Enterprise image that is spread across 7 discs. However my Dell M90 has a bad optical drive and scratches discs. So I used my MBP and Toast Titanium 11.0.2 to create ISOs of all the DVDs.

I tried to boot from USB on the Dell M90, but I cannot get it to "see" the first ISO (plus I have many other ISOs on that external drive). I have a 8GB PNY thumb drive but cannot get the first ISO onto the drive so I can boot from it - that option is no longer in Disk Utility (grrr) and Toast doesn't seem to offer that ability (it only offers optical discs as a destination).

Does anyone know of a way to get an ISO onto a bootable USB flash drive? I also cannot connect to a network until the image (all 7 discs) are installed and the image boots up.

Comment: Segmented Windows 7 image = *Windows 7 System Image Backup*?

Comment: I am not understaning what you are saying in the first paragraph of your Q.  You have 7 disks, a bad optical drive and scratched disks.  If the disks are scratched, how are your creating good ISOs on your Mac?

Comment: This is a preinstalled, complete Windows 7 Enterprise image. Meant to be loaded onto a physical machine (in this case, a Dell M90). The ISOs were created prior to attempting to install the image. The optical drive that scratches discs was never used. The reason it is spread across 7 DVDs is that eases the cost of sending out multiple hard drives. DVDs are cheaper.

Comment: Is your thumbdrive formatted as FAT with a MBR table?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 (*any* version) fits on one disk of any optical media, not sure what is going on with what you have or exactly what it is, that said...

You can't boot from an ISO, you need to burn it to CD/DVD or install it to an external drive of some sort in a way that makes it bootable.

Depending on what is going on here you **may** be able to use Disk Utility.app to create either optical media or a USB drive that is bootable.

Open Disk Utility and select "Scan image for restore" and select the ISO. Attach your USB drive and restore the ISO to that USB drive, which *should* (I believe, it's been a while since I tried this...) give you a bootable Windows install disk.

Also depending on which Mac you have and the OS version BootCamp assistant may be able to create a bootable Windows 7 installer.

Comment: Though the OP hasn't answered my question (in the comment) I assume he is asking to create a bootable or restorable  *Windows 7 System Backup Image* from several DVDs which are splitted parts of a working Windows partition or disk.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. It gave the error, "only UDIF and NDIF images can be scanned. Operation failed with status -50"